# How to render multiple HTML parts with a plain Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, web, dom

This is a static website with hundreds of pages. I need to render elements like a topnav or a newsletter or a strap of content and changing those contents periodically, from JS.

This is what I tried:

```
const components = {
  compartirEnFlex: `<h4>Newsletter</h4>`,
  newsletterEs: `<h4>Compartir</h4>`,
}


const ids = ['newsletterEs', 'compartirEnFlex', 'infoArticulo', 'infoDeLaWebEnFlexIzq']

function renderComponents(objWithComp, idsArr){
  return idsArr.map(function(id){
    for(let component in objWithComp){
      let arrOfIds = Object.keys(objWithComp);
      arrOfIds.map(key => key)
      if(id === key){
        document.getElementById(id).insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', objWithComp[id])
      }
    }    
  })
}
renderComponents(components, ids);
```

Each id has its counterpart in the HTML structure. When I do this individually it works. However, I have to handle this in an elegant way (and there is no possibility for a JS framework like React in this project).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What’s the purpose of `arrOfIds.map(key => key)`?

Comment: unpack the array keys in `arrOfIds`, so I manage to compare two strings in the if condition.

Comment: Have you checked the console? There's an error.

Comment: You wanna use the console you have to put the function in a script in a HTML page, because it is using the 'document' object.

Comment: You can use [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) to prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run your code, you'll see the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: key is not defined` in the console.

That's because `key` in `if(id === key)` is not defined. The line `arrOfIds.map(key => key)` returns the same exact array as `arrOfIds` because [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) "returns a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array."

Here, you don't assign that new array to a variable, so nothing happens. Even if it was, that new array would be a copy of `arrOfIds` because your mapping function `(key) => key` returns `key` for every `key` -- meaning that the output is the same as the input.

---

However, that's not an issue here. If I understand your question correctly, then [**this demo**](https://codepen.io/sbolel/pen/WNGPxgM) should show an example of what you're trying to accomplish. If that's what you want to achieve, then here's a solution:

First, you don't need to iterate for `component` in `objWithComponent` inside `idArr` -- you're already doing that in the `idArr`. You don't need the `ids` array either, because you can get the keys of the components from the `components` object using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

Let's say your HTML looks something like this:

```html
<div>
  <div id="newsletterEs"></div>
  <div id="compartirEnFlex"></div>
  <div id="infoArticulo"></div>
  <div id="infoDeLaWebEnFlexIzq"></div>
</div>
```

Then, using [`Object.keys(components)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get an array of the ids of the components that you have, you can map those to HTML tags. In fact, `map` is not necessary here because `map` *returns a new array*, and unless you need that array later, there's no reason to use `map`. Instead, you can use [`Object.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Here's what that would look like:

```js
const components = {
  compartirEnFlex: `<h4>Newsletter</h4>`,
  newsletterEs: `<h4>Compartir</h4>`,
}

function renderComponents(objWithComp) {
  Object
    .keys(components)
    .forEach((id) => {
      const element = document.getElementById(id)
      const component = objWithComp[id]
      if (component && element) {
        element.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', component)
      }
    })
}

renderComponents(components)
```

Then, when you call `renderComponents`, you can pass just the `components` argument, and only render the components for which divs with corresponding ids exist with an `if` statement.